# Как отсортировать данные выводимые при помощи пути хранящимся в MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Код ниже выводит изображения которые хранятся в папке, а путь к ним хранится в базе данных MySQL. Запрос сортирует изображения по полю `created` и следовательно получается - `ORDER BY images.created DESC`.

Как можно прикрутить сюда кнопку при нажатии на которую данные отсортируются по `ORDER BY images.created ASC`, а при еще одном нажатии все вернется как было - `ORDER BY images.created DESC`?

```
<?php
$img_url = "uploads/";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT images.id as imgid, images.image_name, images.user_id_fk, users.id, users.login FROM images,users WHERE images.user_id_fk = users.id ORDER BY images.created DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '
<div class="column is-one-quarter container1">
    <a href="img.php?img='.$row['imgid'].'">
        <figure class="image image is-square">
            <img style="object-fit: cover; cursor: pointer;" src="'.$img_url.$row['image_name'].'" />
        </figure>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">'.$row['login'].'</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например по простому.

```
<?php
 if($_GET['sort'] == 1){
   echo '<a href="?sort=1" >Сортировать DESC</a>';
   $sort = "ASC";
 }else{
   echo '<a href="?sort=0" >Сортировать ASC</a>';
   $sort = "DESC";
 }

$img_url = "uploads/";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT images.id as imgid, images.image_name, images.user_id_fk, users.id, users.login FROM images,users WHERE images.user_id_fk = users.id ORDER BY images.created ".$sort);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '
<div class="column is-one-quarter container1">
    <a href="img.php?img='.$row['imgid'].'">
        <figure class="image image is-square">
            <img style="object-fit: cover; cursor: pointer;" src="'.$img_url.$row['image_name'].'" />
        </figure>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">'.$row['login'].'</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
';
}
?>
```

Можно и без перезагрузки страницы делать через ajax, а этот скрипт будет обработчик.